# AngularJS: Storing the value generated in the partial into the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, and I have been experimenting with the check boxes.

I have a bunch of check boxes generated from ng-repeat, and I'm storing the number of checked check boxes in a variable that I called `a`. `a` is created in partial itself. Now, how do I access this variable in my controller? Furthermore, I would like to make this variable global (ie. accessible to all controllers), how would I achieve this?

The partial:

```
<p>You have selected: {{ a =(categories | filter:{checked: true }).length }} JOSCOS</p>

    <ul class="a">
    <li ng-repeat="item in categories" >
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" ng-model = "item.checked">{{item.info.ct}}
      </input>
      </li>
     </ul>
```

My angular controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/data/JOSCO.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.categories = data;
  });
}]);
```

Comment: using `$root.a` in the view should work

Answer (score 0):

You should create an service/factory to fetch your data in store it in. Then every controller has access to that service/factory using depencency injection. So your able to attach that data to your controller's $scope

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way.

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.a = {};

  $scope.watch('$scope.a',function () {

     //called here your factory SERVICE which hold this chnages  valued
     //You can use this SERVICE to accec updated value.
  })
}]);
```

Stored this updated value in SERVICE and access it from where you want

Comment: Could you please tell me how I have to call factory service inside the `$watch`?